# Accessing Web API in MVC 5 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a MVC 5 application. I have added ADO.Net Entity Data Model and created the Web API 2 controller using Entity Framework. I have also created the DTO class. Following is my DTO class:

```
public class CollegeDetailsController : ApiController
{
    private CollegeDbContext db = new CollegeDbContext();

    // GET: api/CollegeDetails
    public IQueryable<CollegeDTO> GetCollegeDetails()
    {
        var colleges = from c in db.CollegeDetails
                       select new CollegeDTO()
                       {
                           Name= c.CollegeName,
                           ContactPersonName= c.ContactPerson,
                           CollegeState= c.State,
                           CollegeCity=c.City
                       };
        return colleges;
    }
```

I am accessing this using jQuery:

```
    function GetAllColleges() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:57071/api/collegedetails",
            type: "Get",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { WriteCollegeData(data); },
            error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
        });
    });
}

function WriteCollegeData(colleges) {
    var result = "<table><th>College Name</th><th>Contact Person</th><th>College State</th><th>Contact City</th>";
    $.each(colleges, function (index, item) {
        result += "<tr><td>" + item.Name + "</td><td>" + item.ContactPersonName + "</td><td>" + item.CollegeState + "</td><td>" + item.CollegeCity + "</td></tr>";
    });
    result += "</table>";
    $("#CollegeData").html(result);
}
```

My Cshthml page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "College";
}

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/App");
}

<h2>College Details</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Colleges</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" id= "CollegeData">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

While accessing this page, the data is not binding to the panel and there is no error is coming on console.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just removed the `function GetAllColleges() {}`. Now the values are coming.